# Java Application refuses to display output as Floating Point. Have tried Casting, multiplying 1.0, adding 0.0, nothing works

Tags: java, floating-point, integer-division

## Problem:

I'm having issues calculating Integer Division and display as a Double (Floating Point).

At lower numbers it displays like a floating point, but seems like it rounds the value to something like 11.0, 9.0, 28.0. After attempting to problem solve via other StackO Posts I cannot seem to get it to be consistent. I have through some of the solutions been able to get it to display as a Floating Point solution, but running through the test commands, the results are inconsistent on when they display as floating point or not.

## Homework Request:

Write a program RandomWalkers.java that takes two integer command-line arguments 'r' and 'trials'. In each of trials independent experiments, simulate a random walk until the random walker is at Manhattan distance r from the starting point. Print the average number of steps.

As 'r' increases, we expect the random walker to take more and more steps. But how many more steps? Use RandomWalkers.java to formulate a hypothesis as to how the average number of steps grows as a function of 'r'.

Estimating an unknown quantity by generating random samples and aggregating the results is an example of Monte Carlo simulation — a powerful computational technique that is used widely in statistical physics, computational finance, and computer graphics.

*You may not call library functions except those in the java.lang (such as `Integer.parseInt()` and `Math.sqrt()`). Use only Java features that have already been introduced in the course (e.g., loops and conditionals, but **not arrays**).*

## What I've tried:

- Read at least 30+ different StackOverflow and other various websites pages on displaying Integer Division as Floating Point (Double), etc. and tried everything in those.
- `avgSteps = (double) totalNumSteps / trials;`
- changing some/all Variables to Double
- `(totalNumSteps * 1.0) / trials;`
- `(totalNumSteps + 0.0) / trials;`

I sometimes have a breakthrough, but then I test it a little more and it fails with some or all arguments passed to the application.

## Code:

The below code is the cleaned up base version of the code, minus any tests from above.

```
public class RandomWalkers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int x = 0;
        int xx = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int yy = 0;
        int numSteps = 0;
        int totalNumSteps = 0;
        double randNum = 0.0;
        double avgSteps = 0.0;

        for (long i = 0; i < trials; i++) {
            while (Math.abs(x - xx) + Math.abs(y - yy) != r) {
                randNum = Math.random();
                if (randNum <= .25) {
                    // North
                    yy++;

                } else if (randNum <= .5) {
                    // East
                    xx++;

                } else if (randNum <= .75) {
                    // South
                    yy--;

                } else {
                    // West
                    xx--;

                }
                numSteps++;
            }
            totalNumSteps += numSteps;
        }

        avgSteps = totalNumSteps / trials;
        System.out.println("average number of steps = " + avgSteps);
    }

}
```

## Expected Outcome:

This is the requested parameters, and expected output supplied within the Homework Project Section.

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 5 1000000
```

average number of steps = 14.98188

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 5 1000000
```

average number of steps = 14.93918

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 10 100000
```

average number of steps = 59.37386

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 20 100000
```

average number of steps = 235.6288

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 40 100000
```

average number of steps = 949.14712

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 80 100000
```

average number of steps = 3775.7152

```
~/Desktop/loops> java RandomWalkers 160 100000
```

average number of steps = 15113.61108

## Graded Work (Actual Outcome)

Testing correctness of RandomWalkers

---

Running 7 total tests.

Test 1: check output format

```
% java RandomWalkers 5 10000
```

average number of steps = 9.0

```
% java RandomWalkers 10 1000
```

average number of steps = 18.0

```
% java RandomWalkers 20 123456
```

average number of steps = 150.0

```
% java RandomWalkers 40 1
```

average number of steps = 726.0

```
% java RandomWalkers 1 10000
```

average number of steps = 1.0

```
% java RandomWalkers 0 333
```

average number of steps = 0.0

==> passed

Test 2: check average number of steps (trials = 10000)
  * `java RandomWalkers 1 10000`
  * `java RandomWalkers 2 10000`
    - student average number of steps = 2.000000
    - true average number of steps    = 2.6666666666666665
    - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[2.617080, 2.716254]`
    - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000

- `java RandomWalkers 3 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 3.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 5.5709
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[5.443408, 5.698392]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 4 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 24.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 9.6808
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[9.444787, 9.916813]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 5 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 7.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 14.9775
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[14.602377, 15.352623]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 10 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 52.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 59.1465
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[57.612929, 60.680071]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 20 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 390.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 235.9058
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[229.737686, 242.073914]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 40 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 2056.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 943.3142
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[918.599036, 968.029364]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000

==> **FAILED**

Test 3: check average number of steps (radius = 5)
  * `java RandomWalkers 5 100`
    - student average number of steps = 11.000000
    - true average number of steps    = 14.9775
    - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[11.226273, 18.728727]`
    - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000

- `java RandomWalkers 5 1000`

  - student average number of steps = 7.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 14.9775
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[13.791258, 16.163742]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 5 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 5.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 14.9775
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[14.602377, 15.352623]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 5 100000`

  - student average number of steps = 9.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 14.9775
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[14.858876, 15.096124]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 5 1000000`

  - student average number of steps = 21.000000
  - true average number of steps    = 14.9775
  - 99.99% confidence interval     = `[14.939988, 15.015012]`
  - a correct solution will fail this test by bad luck approximately 1 time in 10,000

==> **FAILED**

Test 4: check average number of steps (radius = 0)
  * `java RandomWalkers 0 1000`
  * `java RandomWalkers 0 100`
  * `java RandomWalkers 0 1`
==> passed

Test 5: check that the average number of steps is not an integer
  * `java RandomWalkers 10 1000`
    - student average number of steps = 70.0
    - a correct solution will fail this test less than 1 time in 10,000

- `java RandomWalkers 7 2500`

  - student average number of steps = 51.0
  - a correct solution will fail this test less than 1 time in 10,000
- `java RandomWalkers 3 10000`

  - student average number of steps = 5.0
  - a correct solution will fail this test less than 1 time in 10,000

==> **FAILED**

Test 6: check that program produces different result each time
  * `java RandomWalkers 10 10000` `[ repeated twice ]`
  * `java RandomWalkers 20 1000` `[ repeated twice ]`
  * `java RandomWalkers 40 2000` `[ repeated twice ]`
==> passed

Test 7: check randomness of average number of steps when trials = 1
  * `java RandomWalkers 2 1` `[ repeated 1024 times ]`
  * `java RandomWalkers 3 1` `[ repeated 8192 times ]`
  * `java RandomWalkers 4 1` `[ repeated 65536 times ]`
  * `java RandomWalkers 5 1` `[ repeated 1048576 times ]`
==> passed

RandomWalkers Total: 4/7 tests passed!

Comment: the code, as posted, could not work since using integer division. But also check the maths involved  - print out the value of `totalNumSteps`

Comment: Please read the [MCVE guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your answer accordingly :)

Comment: You should reset the values of `xx`, `yy` and `numSteps` for each trial, that is, inside the first `for` loop, otherwise `numSteps` will always be the same as for the first iteration

Comment: I see similar errors to this in many algorithms. It is common for those coming from C or those who believe that reassigning to a variable is faster than redeclaring a variable. I have benchmarked the algorithm below using Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH) vs the same algorithm will the variables being declared as close to their actual use-site as possible. The performance between the two was nearly identical with no clear trend on which implementation was faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were two issues here.
1) As noted by Carlos Heuberger, you needed to reinitialize the variables each time through the loop.
2) As you noted, it took some care to get the division to be real number division, not a "div" operator for integers. I made those two changes to your code (first 5 lines in the for loop; (1.0 * trials)), and it appears to pass all tests.
You were close.

```
public class RandomWalkers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int x = 0;
    int xx = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int yy = 0;
    int numSteps = 0;
    int totalNumSteps = 0;
    double randNum = 0.0;
    double avgSteps = 0.0;

    for (long i = 0; i < trials; i++) {
        x = 0;
        xx = 0;
        y = 0;
        yy = 0;
        numSteps = 0;
        while (Math.abs(x - xx) + Math.abs(y - yy) != r) {
            randNum = Math.random();
            if (randNum <= .25) {
                // North
                yy++;

            } else if (randNum <= .5) {
                // East
                xx++;

            } else if (randNum <= .75) {
                // South
                yy--;

            } else {
                // West
                xx--;

            }
            numSteps++;
        }
        totalNumSteps += numSteps;
    }

    avgSteps = totalNumSteps / (1.0 * trials);
    System.out.println("average number of steps = " + avgSteps);


   }

}
```

Comment: it was extra to reinitialize x and y. I did not look that carefully at first. I also see Carlos Heuberger deserves credit for catching both issues. @Carlos Heuberger if you want to post the answer yourself, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution to the answer. I had about 99% of what you have there through my trial and errors and had it working as intended, but due to not resetting the coordinates and steps, each time the for loop ran it introduced other issues where it wouldn't work, so I lead myself down the wrong rabbit hole. Thanks Jeremy and Carlos for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like these tend to happen when variables are declared away from their assignment or use-site.

Using [Java Microbenchmark Harness(JMH)](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) I was unable to see clear performance advantages between reassigning and redeclaring the variables.

However I was able to see a HUGE (over 2x speed up) when replacing `Math.Random` with `RANDOM.nextInt(4)` and `switch`

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomWalkers {

    static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        int totalNumSteps = 0;

        for (long i = 0; i < trials; i++) {
            int x = 0;
            int xx = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int yy = 0;
            int numSteps = 0;

            while (Math.abs(x - xx) + Math.abs(y - yy) != r) {

                switch (RANDOM.nextInt(4)) {
                    case 0:
                        // North
                        yy++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // East
                        xx++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // South
                        yy--;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // West
                        xx--;
                }
                numSteps++;
            }

            totalNumSteps += numSteps;
        }

        double avgSteps = totalNumSteps / (1.0 * trials);
        System.out.println("average number of steps = " + avgSteps);
    }
}
```

*P0.95 Results for an r = 40*

- reassign: 299.368 ms/op
- redeclareRandomIntSwitch: 139.107 ms/op

### We can do better

Explicit `if` conditions, while slightly less readable, are (in this case) faster than `switch`

Further, since we are running in a single threaded context we can replace the `java.util.Random` with `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`.

Also an explicit cast to `double` is clearer than multiplying by `1.0` and saves us two bytecodes.

*P0.95 Results for an r = 40*

- reassign: 299.368 ms/op
- redeclareRandomIntSwitch: 139.107 ms/op
- redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf: 122.539 ms/op

The code below is nearly 2.5x faster.

```java
package com.stackoverflow.q56030483;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class RandomWalker {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        int totalNumSteps = 0;

        final ThreadLocalRandom threadLocalRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

        for (long i = 0; i < trials; i++) {

            int x = 0;

            int xx = 0;

            int y = 0;

            int yy = 0;

            int numSteps = 0;

            while (Math.abs(x - xx) + Math.abs(y - yy) != r) {

                final int direction= threadLocalRandom.nextInt(4);

                // North
                if (direction == 0) {
                    yy++;

                // East
                } else if (direction == 1) {
                    xx++;

                // South
                } else if (direction == 2) {
                    yy--;

                // West
                } else {
                    xx--;
                }

                numSteps++;
            }

            totalNumSteps += numSteps;
        }

        System.out.println("average number of steps = " + totalNumSteps / (double) trials);

    }
}
```

```
Benchmark                                                                (arg)    Mode    Cnt    Score   Error  Units
RandomWalkers.reassign                                                       3  sample  37256    1.611 ± 0.002  ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.00                                        3  sample           1.475          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.50                                        3  sample           1.593          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.90                                        3  sample           1.686          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.95                                        3  sample           1.780          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.99                                        3  sample           1.999          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.999                                       3  sample           2.507          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.9999                                      3  sample           4.367          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p1.00                                        3  sample          10.371          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign                                                      10  sample   3528   17.029 ± 0.063  ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.00                                       10  sample          15.548          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.50                                       10  sample          16.712          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.90                                       10  sample          18.416          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.95                                       10  sample          18.842          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.99                                       10  sample          20.690          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.999                                      10  sample          27.636          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.9999                                     10  sample          36.176          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p1.00                                       10  sample          36.176          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign                                                      40  sample    227  268.714 ± 3.270  ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.00                                       40  sample         251.134          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.50                                       40  sample         262.144          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.90                                       40  sample         296.223          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.95                                       40  sample         299.368          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.99                                       40  sample         303.416          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.999                                      40  sample         305.136          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p0.9999                                     40  sample         305.136          ms/op
RandomWalkers.reassign:reassign·p1.00                                       40  sample         305.136          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch                                       3  sample  69486    0.863 ± 0.001  ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.00        3  sample           0.763          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.50        3  sample           0.843          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.90        3  sample           0.925          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.95        3  sample           1.028          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.99        3  sample           1.155          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.999       3  sample           1.721          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.9999      3  sample           5.181          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p1.00        3  sample           9.355          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch                                      10  sample   7072    8.485 ± 0.040  ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.00       10  sample           7.668          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.50       10  sample           8.143          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.90       10  sample           9.650          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.95       10  sample          10.109          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.99       10  sample          11.960          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.999      10  sample          20.399          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.9999     10  sample          25.919          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p1.00       10  sample          25.919          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch                                      40  sample    466  130.302 ± 0.872  ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.00       40  sample         123.732          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.50       40  sample         128.844          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.90       40  sample         135.083          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.95       40  sample         139.107          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.99       40  sample         155.153          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.999      40  sample         182.452          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p0.9999     40  sample         182.452          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareRandomIntSwitch:redeclareRandomIntSwitch·p1.00       40  sample         182.452          ms/op

RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf                                               40  sample   96  107.953 ± 2.148  ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.00          40  sample        99.746          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.50          40  sample       107.676          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.90          40  sample       113.797          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.95          40  sample       122.539          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.99          40  sample       130.810          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.999         40  sample       130.810          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p0.9999     40  sample       130.810          ms/op
RandomWalkers.redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf:redeclareThreadLocalRandomIntIf·p1.00       40  sample       130.810          ms/op
```

Comment: Although your answer is probably correct on a performance level as well as a fundamental level. The assignment required that we utilize base Java functionality without using Array's, importing library files, etc.

I do appreciate the information you supplied as it will definitely help in how I code in the future as our knowledge is expanded as well as the code we are allowed to use.

Comment: An important thing to note is that  `java.lang.Math's` `random` is simply delegating to `java.util.Random`, meaning the actual library dependency footprint is identical for both implementations. 


The fact that `java.util.Random` is not `java.lang.Random`, which would have allowed it to be accessible without an import statement, is merely an accident of history.